# Return pre-UPDATE column values using SQL only

Tags: sql, postgresql, concurrency, sql-update, subquery

[I posted a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7922211/902825), but this is another part of my puzzle.

I would like to get the OLD value of a column from a row that was UPDATEd - WITHOUT using triggers (nor stored procedures, nor any other extra, non -SQL/-query entities).

I have a query like this:

```
   UPDATE my_table
      SET processing_by = our_id_info  -- unique to this worker
    WHERE trans_nbr IN (
                        SELECT trans_nbr
                          FROM my_table
                         GROUP BY trans_nbr
                        HAVING COUNT(trans_nbr) > 1
                         LIMIT our_limit_to_have_single_process_grab
                       )
RETURNING row_id;
```

If I could do `FOR UPDATE ON my_table` at the end of the subquery, that'd be divine (and fix my other question/problem). But that won't work: can't combine this with `GROUP BY` (which is necessary for figuring out the count). Then I could just take those trans_nbr's and do a query first to get the (soon-to-be-) former `processing_by` values.

I've tried doing like:

```
   UPDATE my_table
      SET processing_by = our_id_info -- unique to this worker
     FROM my_table old_my_table
     JOIN (
             SELECT trans_nbr
               FROM my_table
           GROUP BY trans_nbr
             HAVING COUNT(trans_nbr) > 1
              LIMIT our_limit_to_have_single_process_grab
          ) sub_my_table
       ON old_my_table.trans_nbr = sub_my_table.trans_nbr
    WHERE     my_table.trans_nbr = sub_my_table.trans_nbr
      AND my_table.processing_by = old_my_table.processing_by
RETURNING my_table.row_id, my_table.processing_by, old_my_table.processing_by
```

But that can't work; `old_my_table` is not visible outside the join; the `RETURNING` clause is blind to it.

I've long since lost count of all the attempts I've made; I have been researching this for literally hours.

If I could just find a bullet-proof way to lock the rows in my subquery - and ONLY those rows, and WHEN the subquery happens - all the concurrency issues I'm trying to avoid would disappear ...

---

**UPDATE:** I had a typo in the non-generic code of the above. I retried after Erwin Brandstetter suggested it should work. Since it took me so long to find this sort of solution, perhaps my embarrassment is worth it? At least this is on SO for posterity now...  :>

What I now have (that works) is like this:

```
   UPDATE my_table
      SET processing_by = our_id_info -- unique to this worker
     FROM my_table AS old_my_table
    WHERE trans_nbr IN (
                          SELECT trans_nbr
                            FROM my_table
                        GROUP BY trans_nbr
                          HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
                           LIMIT our_limit_to_have_single_process_grab
                       )
      AND my_table.row_id = old_my_table.row_id
RETURNING my_table.row_id, my_table.processing_by, old_my_table.processing_by AS old_processing_by
```

The `COUNT(*)` is per a suggestion from **Flimzy** in a comment on my other (linked above) question.

[Please see my other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7922211/902825) for correctly implementing concurrency and even a non-blocking version; THIS query merely shows how to get the old and new values from an update, ignore the bad/wrong concurrency bits.

Comment: Why can't you use a rule or trigger?

Comment: Best way IMHO is to make the old rows historic, either by explicit SQL, or by a rewrite rule or trigger.

Comment: @Flimzy: 1. If one didn't have access to such things (though *I* do), if it CAN be done purely in SQL/single query...  2. Rules/triggers are a whole 'nother debug enchilada.  3. Keeping it simple, straight SQL, and having One Query To Do It All does K.I.S.S. nicely.  Thanks, again, for the count(*) reminder, tho!  :>

Comment: @wildplasser: The goal is to get back (1) what was changed and (2) what was there before the change (at least).  This is handy for jobs where what will be changed isn't explicitly known up front, but the program should know what the old vals were for processing.  (Outputting before/after for troubleshooting, for example.)  Historic rows are unnecessary clutter, rules and triggers are not only cruft (for this use case), but also require "more" (security, access, etc.).  For those who don't have/want/need these, this solution is the best.

Answer (score 119, accepted):

#### Problem

[The manual explains](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-update.html):

> The optional `RETURNING` clause causes `UPDATE` to compute and return
> value(s) based on each row actually updated. Any expression using the
> table's columns, and/or columns of other tables mentioned in `FROM`, can
> be computed. The **new (post-update) values of the table's columns are
> used**. The syntax of the `RETURNING` list is identical to that of the
> output list of `SELECT`.

Bold emphasis mine. There is no way to access the old row in a `RETURNING` clause. You can work around this restriction with a trigger or a separate `SELECT` *before* the `UPDATE` wrapped in a transaction or wrapped in a CTE as was commented.

However, what you are trying to achieve **works perfectly fine** if you join to another instance of the table in the `FROM` clause:

#### Solution without concurrent writes

```
UPDATE tbl x
SET    tbl_id = 23
     , name = 'New Guy'
FROM   tbl y                -- using the FROM clause
WHERE  x.tbl_id = y.tbl_id  -- must be UNIQUE NOT NULL
AND    x.tbl_id = 3
RETURNING y.tbl_id AS old_id, y.name AS old_name
        , x.tbl_id          , x.name;
```

Returns:

```
 old_id | old_name | tbl_id |  name
--------+----------+--------+---------
  3     | Old Guy  | 23     | New Guy
```

The column(s) used to self-join must be `UNIQUE NOT NULL`. In the simple example, the `WHERE` condition is on the same column `tbl_id`, but that's just coincidence. Works for *any* conditions.

I tested this with PostgreSQL versions from 8.4 to 13.

It's different for `INSERT`:

- [INSERT INTO ... FROM SELECT ... RETURNING id mappings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29256888/insert-into-from-select-returning-id-mappings/29263402#29263402)

#### Solutions with concurrent write load

There are various ways to avoid race conditions with concurrent write operations on the same rows. (Note that concurrent write operations on unrelated rows are no problem at all.) The simple, slow and sure (but expensive) method is to run the transaction with [`SERIALIZABLE` isolation level](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/transaction-iso.html#XACT-SERIALIZABLE):

```
BEGIN ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE;
UPDATE ... ;
COMMIT;
```

But that's probably overkill. And you need to be prepared to repeat the operation in case of a serialization failure.

Simpler and faster (and just as reliable with concurrent write load) is an explicit lock on the *one* row to be updated:

```
UPDATE tbl x
SET    tbl_id = 24
     , name = 'New Gal'
FROM  (SELECT tbl_id, name FROM tbl WHERE tbl_id = 4 FOR UPDATE) y 
WHERE  x.tbl_id = y.tbl_id
RETURNING y.tbl_id AS old_id, y.name AS old_name
        , x.tbl_id          , x.name;
```

Note how the `WHERE` condition moved to the subquery (again, can be *anything*), and only the self-join (on `UNIQUE NOT NULL` column(s)) remains in the outer query. This guarantees that only rows locked by the inner `SELECT` are processed. The `WHERE` conditions might resolve to a different set of rows a moment later.

See:

- [Atomic UPDATE .. SELECT in Postgres](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11532550/atomic-update-select-in-postgres)

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=fe12dd086a97fba3b0e125c8926ebe88)*
<sub>Old [sqlfiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!17/7dd0c7/1)</sub>

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: Do you happen to have a 9.1 cluster at hand where you could run this little test in? To make things complete .. :)

Comment: Works on 9.1 just as well (I would have been **very** surprised if it didn't)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: Thank you! Same here, but knowing >> assuming. :)

Comment: Not to pick nits, but I might suggest editing your answer, @ErwinBrandstetter, as a passer-by might stop reading the top portion ("_it can't be done_") and miss your **totally rockin' proof that it can**!  Regardless, thanks, again!  :o)

Comment: @PythonLarry: this *edit* should help the pessimists among us. :)

Comment: Cheers @Erwin Brandstetter. Next step would be to create a recursive version of this beauty ;-) I fear it's not allowed to have side effects in the recursive CTE, though.

Comment: It works well until it doesn't. For me it happens with running the same request with different parameters with reasonably small delay (about 10 milliseconds). In this case following requests will have old value from one of followed requests  (read as 'object having different key'), not the running one. *So use that with caution in cases with heavy load!*

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter what about using a subquery as I suggest? http://stackoverflow.com/a/22734004/242933

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter Why do you need `WHERE  x.tbl_id = y.tbl_id`?

Comment: @MattDiPasquale: We are joining to a second instance of the same table under a different alias. We need a join condition or it's going to be a cross join (Cartesian product).

Comment: If the target table does not have `UNIQUE NOT NULL` column, we can join using the `ctid` system column; `WHERE x.ctid = y.ctid`.

Comment: Every time I have a PG question all I need is to look for @ErwinBrandstetter responses. This guy is The Matrix's equivalent of Neo to PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 29):

You can use a `SELECT` subquery.

Example: [Update](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/sql-update.html) a user's email `RETURNING` the old value.

1. `RETURNING` Subquery

   ```
   UPDATE users SET email = 'new@gmail.com' WHERE id = 1
   RETURNING (SELECT email FROM users WHERE id = 1);
   ```
2. [PostgreSQL WITH Query (Common Table Expressions)](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/queries-with.html)

   ```
   WITH u AS (
       SELECT email FROM users WHERE id = 1
   )
   UPDATE users SET email = 'new@gmail.com' WHERE id = 1
   RETURNING (SELECT email FROM u);
   ```

   This has worked several times on my local database without fail, but I'm not sure if the `SELECT` in `WITH` is guaranteed to consistently execute before the `UPDATE` since "the sub-statements in WITH are executed concurrently with each other and with the main query."

Comment: Do both solutions work consistently under heavy load? If yes, prove it. If not, how can they be modified so that they do?

Comment: Sounds like that should rather be a question, then. You can always link to this one for context ...

Comment: @2: "All the statements are executed with the same snapshot (see Chapter 13), so they cannot "see" one another's effects on the target tables. This alleviates the effects of the unpredictability of the actual order of row updates, and means that RETURNING data is the only way to communicate changes between different WITH sub-statements and the main query." -- https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/queries-with.html

Comment: Something to note here is this only works if you're updating a single row. If the WHERE clause selects multiple rows, you get an error: "more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression".

Answer (score 13):

The CTE variant [proposed here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22734004/939860) works too.
With the comfortable means of a CTE I would be more explicit, though:

```sql
WITH sel AS (
   SELECT tbl_id, name
   FROM   tbl
   WHERE  tbl_id = 3  -- assuming unique tbl_id
   )
, upd AS (
   UPDATE tbl
   SET    name = 'New Guy'
   WHERE  tbl_id = 3
   RETURNING tbl_id, name
   )
SELECT s.tbl_id AS old_id, s.name As old_name
     , u.tbl_id, u.name
FROM   sel s, upd u;
```

`SELECT` and `UPDATE` see the same snapshot of the database. The `SELECT` is bound to return the old values (even if you place the CTE after the CTE with the `UPDATE`), while the `UPDATE` returns the new values by definition. Voilá.

But it will be slower than my first answer.

Comment: Do you see any immediate issues using the subquery method? (performance or otherwise)

Comment: @calebboyd: The only immediate "issue": it's faster than the CTE variant. Also consider the version defending against possible concurrency issues discussed in the other answer.

Comment: I guess that might be what I was wondering -- Do you know if the subquery would exhibit the similar concurrency issues? -- may be a separate question...

Comment: In READ COMMITTED, when the update statement is blocked by another transaction, the select statement will not be rerun, after the other transaction commits. So it will return the original value (existing before both transactions) not the one which is actually overwritten by the update statement. I guess it depends on the use case if that matters or not.

Comment: @Joe23: Yes, that's an important detail to be aware of. I am addressing that in my main answer with a `FOR UPDATE` lock to avoid the race condition.

Answer (score 2):

when faced with this dilemma I added junk columns to the table and then I copy the old values into the junk columns (which I then return) when I update the record. this bloats the table a bit but avoids the need for joins.