# Is it possible (how?) to return old value from "after update" trigger

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update, postgresql-9.3

```
UPDATE "Users" 
SET "displayName" = 'new_name' 
WHERE id = 1 
RETURNING "displayName"
```

Query above returns **NEW** value.
I want to know **OLD** value of `displayName` after update. I know that it possible to:

```
 UPDATE ... 
 FROM SELECT ... 
 RETURNING ...
```

but I want to use `AFTER UPDATE` trigger. Is it possible to "return" old value from `AFTER UPDATE` trigger somehow? If yes how such trigger body will look like?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes it is, but **no triggers** are involved here at all. Just a plain `UPDATE`.

The `RETURNING` clause returns values based on the row *after* the update. But you can include the old row in a `FROM` clause and use *that*. [Per documentation:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-update.html)

> Any expression using the table's columns, and/or columns of other tables mentioned in `FROM`, can be computed. The new (post-update) values of the table's columns are used.

Solution:

```sql
UPDATE "Users" x
SET    "displayName" = 'new_name' 
FROM  (SELECT id, "displayName" FROM "Users" WHERE id = 1 FOR UPDATE) y 
WHERE  x.id = y.id
RETURNING y."displayName";
```

Detailed explanation:

- [Return pre-UPDATE column values using SQL only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7923237/return-pre-update-column-values-using-sql-only-postgresql-version/7927957#7927957)

#### What if my ORM does not allow a `FROM` clause?

Are you sure? If so, a simple (more expensive) alternative would be to run two statements:

```sql
BEGIN;
-- Retrieve old value first;
SELECT "displayName" FROM "Users" WHERE id = 1 FOR UPDATE;

UPDATE "Users"
SET    "displayName" = 'new_name' 
WHERE  id = 1;

COMMIT;
```

The transaction wrapper (`BEGIN; ... COMMIT;`) and the lock on the row (`FOR UPDATE`) are to defend against possible concurrent writes. You can remove both if you are the only one writing to that table or if an occasional outdated "old value" is ok. Rarely happens except in very competitive setups.

Or use raw SQL to bypass your inferior ORM.

I can imagine tricks to work around this (like adding a redundant column with the pre-update value of `"displayName"`), but such trickery sounds like a *very bad idea*. Just use the standard functionality.

Comment: Hey, in my question I wrote that I know this method (read carefully) and "but I want to use AFTER UPDATE trigger". And yes I have read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7923237/return-pre-update-column-values-using-sql-only-postgresql-version/7927957#7927957 before but I want to use triggers. The reason I want to use trigger is that ORM I am using won't allow me to use `UPDATE...SET...FROM` "method".

Comment: @user606521: ORMs are crude crutches, some of them butcher the functionality of the underlying RDBMS. Just use raw SQL. The `RETURNING` clause returns what has actually been written to the column. An `AFTER TRIGGER` won't change that. An alternative would be to use a [data-modifying CTE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/queries-with.html#QUERIES-WITH-MODIFYING). But if your ORM fails with a simple, basic `FROM` clause, I imagine it won't allow that either.

Comment: Ok, thanks - please modify your answer pointing that it can't be done using trigger and I will accept it.

Comment: @user606521: I added some more.