# Returning multiple values from UPDATE query in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update, plpgsql, sql-returning

I'm new to writing DB functions and I need to return the value of 'last_login_at' as `OUT` parameter when performing an `UPDATE` query.

Here is a snippet of my function:

```
...
LOOP
    UPDATE "user" SET 
        last_login_at = current_timestamp, 
        first_name = p_first_name,
        last_name = p_last_name,
    WHERE ext_user_id = p_ext_user_id AND platform_id = p_platform_id
    RETURNING id INTO v_user_id;
    is_new := false;
    // The next 'CASE' is not valid - Need to replace it with a valid one.  
    has_logged_in_today = CASE
     WHEN date_part('day', age(current_timestamp, last_login_at)) > 1
     THEN true
     ELSE false
     END;
    IF FOUND THEN 
        EXIT;
    END IF;
..
..
END LOOP;
```

Is it possible to do multiple `RETURNING x INTO y`?
Can we use a `CASE` statement in `RETURNING x INTO y`?

#### EDIT

I was able to get better results and now it looks like this:

```
   ...
    LOOP
        UPDATE "user" SET 
            login_consecutive_days = CASE 
                WHEN date_part('day', age(current_timestamp, last_login_at)) > 1 
                THEN 0
                ELSE login_consecutive_days + date_part('day', age(current_timestamp, last_login_at))
                END,
        login_max_consecutive_days = CASE
        WHEN date_part('day', age(current_timestamp, last_login_at)) = 1
             AND (login_consecutive_days+1 > login_max_consecutive_days)
        THEN login_consecutive_days+1
        ELSE login_max_consecutive_days
        END,
        last_login_at = current_timestamp, 
            num_sessions = num_sessions + 1,
            last_update_source = 'L',
            first_name = p_first_name,
            last_name = p_last_name,
            additional_data = p_additional_data
        WHERE ext_user_id = p_ext_user_id AND platform_id = p_platform_id
        RETURNING id,
        CASE
        WHEN date_part('day', age(current_timestamp, last_login_at)) = 0
        THEN true
        ELSE false
        END
    INTO v_user_id, is_first_login_today;
        is_new := false;
        IF FOUND THEN 
            EXIT;
        END IF;
    ...
```

The only problem with this is that at the point of `RETURNING` the `last_login_at` has already been updated so `CASE` always returns `TRUE`.

Is there a magical solution to my problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is there a magical solution to my problem?

Actually, there is: Join to another instance of the `"user"` table in the `FROM` clause:

```
   UPDATE "user" u
   SET    login_consecutive_days = ...  -- unqualified column name

   FROM   "user" u1
   WHERE  u.ext_user_id = p_ext_user_id
   AND    u.platform_id = p_platform_id
   AND    u.id = u1.id                  -- must be unique not null (like the PK)
   RETURNING u.id, (u1.last_login_at < now() + interval '1 day')
   INTO   v_user_id, is_first_login_today;

   is_new := false;
   EXIT WHEN FOUND;
```

Now, the table alias `u` refers to the post-`UPDATE` state of the table, but `u1` refers to a snapshot at the start of the query.

Detailed explanation:

- **[Return pre-UPDATE Column Values Using SQL Only - PostgreSQL Version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7923237/return-pre-update-column-values-using-sql-only-postgresql-version/7927957#7927957)**

Table-qualify all column references to be unambiguous, which is never a bad idea, but after the self-join it's required.

[The manual about the short syntax `EXIT WHEN FOUND`.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-CONTROL-STRUCTURES-LOOPS)

You can use any expression in the `RETURNING` clause, including `CASE` statements. There just happens to be a simpler, cheaper way for this:

```
CASE WHEN date_part('day', age(current_timestamp, last_login_at)) = 0
THEN true ELSE false END
```

Step 1:

```
CASE WHEN last_login_at < now() + interval '1 day'
THEN true ELSE false END
```

Step 2:

```
(last_login_at < now() + interval '1 day')
```

Just use the `boolean` result. If `last_login_at` is `NULL`, you get `NULL`.

---

Asides:
As for the rest of the query: expressions can be simplified, the `LOOP` is suspicious, you should *never* use [reserved words](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-keywords-appendix.html) as identifiers, even though double-quoting makes it possible (<strike>`"user"`</strike>), the algorithm seems to depend on being executed in *exact* 24h intervals, which is error-prone.

Comment: WOW!! I'm more than impressed! thank you so much for this detailed answer - I learned new useful stuff from you!

Comment: Is there a "+="  operator in plpgsql?

Comment: @Shvalb: No, there isn't. Must be `x := x + 1`.

Comment: any comment by @ErwinBrandstetter  is goldmine in postgres ecosystem

Answer (score 2):

You can return multiple columns with a syntax of:

```
UPDATE "user" SET 
        last_login_at = current_timestamp, 
        first_name = p_first_name,
        last_name = p_last_name,
    WHERE ext_user_id = p_ext_user_id AND platform_id = p_platform_id
    RETURNING id, last_login_at 
        INTO v_user_id, v_login_at;
```

The returning clause follows most of the rules of a SELECT field list so you can add as many columns as you need.

[Update docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-update.html)

Comment: Can I use "CASE, WHEN , END" for setting the value?

Comment: Can I do something like: 
RETURNING id, CASE WHEN x THEN yELSE z INTO v_user_id, v_login_at;      is this possible?

Comment: Yes, it's working *BUT* there is an issue: What I really interested to do is accessing the value of 'last_login_at' before it gets updated by the query then do a calculation and return the results using the OUT parameter. Is there a way to access the value of 'last_login_at' without making an explicit SELECT?

Comment: Post what you've got in a fiddle at sqlfiddle.com  that'll make it easier for people to see what you're doing.

Comment: Is it possible to add a function to sqlfiddle?

Comment: Yes.  but you might need to change the query terminator from ";" to something you're not using. like "GO"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83886/discussion-between-shvalb-and-gary).