# RETURNING rows using unnest()?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, set-returning-functions, sql-returning

I'm trying to return a set of rows after doing `UPDATE`.

Something like this.

```
UPDATE Notis new_noti SET notis = '{}'::noti_record_type[] 
FROM (SELECT * FROM Notis WHERE user_id = 2 FOR UPDATE) old_noti 
WHERE old_noti.user_id = new_noti.user_id RETURNING unnest(old_noti.notis);
```

but postgres complains, rightly so:

> set-valued function called in context that cannot accept a set

How am I supposed to go about implementing this?

That is, `RETURNING` a set of rows from `SELECT`ed array after `UPDATE`?

I'm aware that a function can achieve this using `RETURNS SETOF` but rather prefer not to if possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [WITH statement](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/queries-with.html):

```
WITH upd AS (
    UPDATE Notis new_noti SET notis = '{}'::noti_record_type[] 
    FROM (SELECT * FROM Notis WHERE user_id = 2 FOR UPDATE) old_noti 
    WHERE old_noti.user_id = new_noti.user_id RETURNING old_noti.notis
    )
SELECT unnest(notis) FROM upd;
```

Comment: Aha! Thank you so much. Just one more thing. If the noti_record_type is custom type, how can I unwrap that to proper columns by each type key? Currently it returns with single column named `unnest`.

Comment: `select (unnest(notis)).col1, (unnest(notis)).col2 from upd`

Answer (score 3):

Use a [data-modifying CTE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html#QUERIES-WITH-MODIFYING).
You *can* use a set-returning function in the `SELECT` list, but it is cleaner to move it to the `FROM` list with a `LATERAL` subquery since Postgres **9.3**. Especially if you need to extract *multiple* columns (from a *row type* like you commented). It would also be inefficient to call `unnest()` multiple times.

```sql
WITH upd AS (
   UPDATE notis n
   SET    notis = '{}'::noti_record_type[]  -- explicit cast optional
   FROM  (
      SELECT user_id, notis
      FROM   notis
      WHERE  user_id = 2
      FOR    UPDATE
      ) old_n
    WHERE old_n.user_id = n.user_id
    RETURNING old_n.notis
    )
SELECT n.*
FROM   upd u, unnest(u.notis) n;  -- implicit CROSS JOIN LATERAL
```

If the array can be empty and you want to preserve empty / NULL results use `LEFT JOIN LATERAL ... ON true`. See:

- [What is the difference between LATERAL JOIN and a subquery in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28550679/what-is-the-difference-between-lateral-and-a-subquery-in-postgresql/28557803#28557803)
- [Call a set-returning function with an array argument multiple times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26107915/call-a-set-returning-function-with-an-array-argument-multiple-times/26514968#26514968)

<strike>Also, multiple set-returning functions in the same `SELECT` can exhibit surprising behavior. Avoid that.</strike>
This has been sanitized with Postgres 10. See:

- [What is the expected behaviour for multiple set-returning functions in SELECT clause?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39863505/what-is-the-expected-behaviour-for-multiple-set-returning-functions-in-select-cl/39864815#39864815)

Alternative to unnest *multiple* arrays in parallel before and after Postgres 10:

- [Unnest multiple arrays in parallel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27836674/passing-arrays-to-stored-procedures-in-postgres/27854382#27854382)

Related:

- [Return pre-UPDATE column values using SQL only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7923237/return-pre-update-column-values-using-sql-only-postgresql-version/7927957#7927957)

### Behavior of composite / row values

Postgres has an **oddity** when assigning a row type (or composite or record type) from a set-returning function to a column list. One might expect that the row-type field is treated as *one* column and assigned to the respective column, but that is not so. It is decomposed automatically (one row-layer only!) and assigned element-by-element.

So this does not work as expected:

```
SELECT (my_row).*
FROM   upd u, unnest(u.notis) n(my_row);
```

But this does ([like @klin commented)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32273661/returning-rows-using-unnest/32278725?noredirect=1#comment52446876_32278725):

```
SELECT (my_row).*
FROM   upd u, unnest(u.notis) my_row;
```

Or the simpler version I ended up using:

```
SELECT n.*
FROM   upd u, unnest(u.notis) n;
```

Another oddity: A composite (or row) type with a **single field** is decomposed automatically. Thus, table alias and column alias end up doing the same in the outer `SELECT` list:

```
SELECT n FROM unnest(ARRAY[1,2,3]) n;
SELECT n FROM unnest(ARRAY[1,2,3]) n(n);
SELECT n FROM unnest(ARRAY[1,2,3]) t(n);
SELECT t FROM unnest(ARRAY[1,2,3]) t(n);  -- except output column name is "t"
```

For more than one field, the row-wrapper is preserved:

```
SELECT t FROM unnest(ARRAY[1,2,3]) WITH ORDINALITY t(n);  -- requires 9.4+
```

Confused? There is more. For composite types (the case at hand) like:

```
CREATE TYPE my_type AS (id int, txt text);
```

While this works as expected:

```
SELECT n FROM unnest(ARRAY[(1, 'foo')::my_type, (2, 'bar')::my_type]) n;
```

You are in for a **surprise** here:

```
SELECT n FROM unnest(ARRAY[(1, 'foo')::my_type, (2, 'bar')::my_type]) n(n);
```

And that's **the error I had**: When providing a column list, Postgres decomposes the row and assigns provided names one-by-one. Referring to `n` in the `SELECT` list does not return the composite type, but only the (renamed) first element. I had mistakenly expected the row type and tried to decompose with `(my_row).*` - which only returns the first element nonetheless.

Then again:

```
SELECT t FROM unnest(ARRAY[(1, 'foo')::my_type, (2, 'bar')::my_type]) t(n);
```

(Be aware that the first element has been renamed to `"n"`!)

With the new form of `unnest()` taking multiple array arguments (**Postgres 9.4+**):

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   unnest(ARRAY[(1, 'foo')::my_type, (2, 'bar')::my_type]
            , ARRAY[(3, 'baz')::my_type, (4, 'bak')::my_type]) n;
```

Column aliases only for the first two output columns:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   unnest(ARRAY[(1, 'foo')::my_type, (2, 'bar')::my_type]
            , ARRAY[(3, 'baz')::my_type, (4, 'bak')::my_type]) n(a, b);
```

Column aliases for all output columns:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   unnest(ARRAY[(1,'foo')::my_type, (2,'bar')::my_type]
            , ARRAY[(3,'baz')::my_type, (4,'bak')::my_type]) n(a,b,c,d);
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=33793113c98d01512b509d012097924e)*
<sub>Old [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/52ad0/1)</sub>

Comment: Your query will raise an error. Should be `select (my_row).* from upd u, unnest(u.notis) my_row`

Comment: @klin: You are right, sorry I did not test. I am using an even simpler variant now and added an explanation.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter In your last example. since unnest will generate 4 columns. You only provide 2 column alias/name, then the other two columns will use the default composite type's name. 
Like `select * from unnest(ARRAY[1,2], ARRAY['foo','bar','baz']) as x(a);` the returned result first column is **a**, the second column is **unnest**. 
You should add another example:  `select * from unnest(
    array[(1,'foo')::my_type, (2,'bar')::my_type],
    array[(3,'baz')::my_type,(4,'bak')::my_type]
    ) n(a,b,c,d);`

Comment: @Mark: I added your last example for completeness.Updated some details while being at it. The answer is from 2015, originally!

Answer (score 0):

Probably
For:

```
SELECT *
FROM   unnest (ARRAY[(1, 'foo')::my_type, (2, 'bar')::my_type]
             , ARRAY[(3, 'baz')::my_type, (4, 'bak')::my_type]) n(a, b);
```

Use:

```
SELECT *
FROM   unnest (ARRAY[(1, 'foo')::text, (2, 'bar')::text]
             , ARRAY[(3, 'baz')::text, (4, 'bak')::text]) WITH ORDINALITY AS t(first_col, second_col);
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please format your code to make it more readable!