# How do I return a table from a function with a bespoke column name?

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql, dynamic-sql

This function works:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.a()
 RETURNS TABLE(a text)
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
BEGIN
    return query execute
    'select a from ztable';
END;
$function$;
```

But when I try to add some text to the column name:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.a(prefix text)
 RETURNS TABLE(a text)
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
BEGIN
    return query execute
    'select a as $1_a from ztable' using prefix;
END;
$function$;
```

This just fails as a syntax error on $1.
Or:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.a(prefix text)
 RETURNS TABLE(a text)
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
BEGIN
    return query execute
    'select a as '||prefix||'_a from ztable';
END;
$function$;
```

`select * from a('some prefix')` doesn't work.
Is there some other syntax that does the job?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's simply not possible. SQL does not allow dynamic column names.

You must assign a column alias with the *call*. Like:

```
SELECT a AS prefix_a FROM public.a();
```

Or in a column definition list directly attached to the function:

```
SELECT * FROM public.a() AS f(prefix_a);
```

Or, while dealing with a *single* output column, even just:

```
SELECT * FROM public.a() AS prefix_a;
```

See:

- [RETURNING rows using unnest()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32273661/returning-rows-using-unnest/32278725#32278725)