# SQL UPDATE: return if row was updated AND exists

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update

I wrote a query for my API where I must return a `conflict` if the resource is not in a valid state for the request or `not found` if the resource does not exists.

I do not want to send 2 queries to the database (to check whether the resource exists first, then update it). Because just checking if the row was updated is not enough, maybe the resource does not exists.

I always want a row returned which look like this:

```
 exists | updated
--------+---------
 t      | t
(1 row)
```

My query works, I just wonder if there's a simpler approach to...

```
WITH updates AS (
    UPDATE abc
    SET status = 'cancelled'
    WHERE id = $1 AND status = 'active' RETURNING 1
)
SELECT
    EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM abc WHERE id = $1) as exists,
    EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM updates) as updated
```

Comment: Your method seems fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It occurred to me that you could do this if only `RETURNING` could provide the original `status` before the `UPDATE`. This is not possible, but [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7923237/return-pre-update-column-values-using-sql-only-postgresql-version) points out a trick: join to another copy of the same table, and return the *other* table's column!

So this appears to work in your case:

```
UPDATE  t
SET     status = (CASE WHEN t.status = 'active' THEN 'canceled' ELSE t.status END)
FROM    t AS t2
WHERE   t.id = t2.id
AND     t.id = 1
RETURNING t.id, t.status, t2.status
;
```

Of course you could tweak that `RETURNING` to give something more descriptive, e.g. `CASE WHEN t2.status = 'active' THEN 'updated' ELSE 'invalid' END)`, but I show how to return all "interesting" values here to demonstrate what's possible. So: If `id` is missing, you get no result. If `id` is present but already non-`active`, then both `status` columns match. If it was updated, then the `status` columns differ.

Comment: Pretty clever. Also I didn't knew you could use FROM after the update statement!