# RETURNING causes error: missing FROM-clause entry for table

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-insert, greatest-n-per-group, sql-returning

I am getting the users data from UUID `WHERE empl_user_pub_uuid = 'e2bb39f1f28011eab66c63cb4d9c7a34'`.

Since I don't want to make an additional query to fetch additional user data I'm trying to sneak them through the `INSERT`.

```
WITH _u AS (
    SELECT
        eu.empl_user_pvt_uuid,
        ee.email,
        ep.name_first
    FROM employees.users eu
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT DISTINCT ON (ee.empl_user_pvt_uuid)
            ee.empl_user_pvt_uuid,
            ee.email
        FROM employees.emails ee
        ORDER BY ee.empl_user_pvt_uuid, ee.t DESC
    ) ee ON eu.empl_user_pvt_uuid = ee.empl_user_pvt_uuid
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT DISTINCT ON (ep.empl_user_pvt_uuid)
            ep.empl_user_pvt_uuid,
            ep.name_first
        FROM employees.profiles ep
    ) ep ON eu.empl_user_pvt_uuid = ep.empl_user_pvt_uuid
    WHERE empl_user_pub_uuid = 'e2bb39f1f28011eab66c63cb4d9c7a34'
)
INSERT INTO employees.password_resets (empl_pwd_reset_uuid, empl_user_pvt_uuid, t_valid, for_empl_user_pvt_uuid, token)
SELECT 'f70a0346-a077-11eb-bd1a-aaaaaaaaaaaa', '6efc2b7a-f27e-11ea-b66c-de1c405de048', '2021-04-18 19:57:47.111365', _u.empl_user_pvt_uuid, '19d65aea-7c4a-41bc-b580-9d047f1503e6'
FROM _u
RETURNING _u.empl_user_pvt_uuid, _u.email, _u.name_first;
```

However I get:

> ```
> [42P01] ERROR: missing FROM-clause entry for table "_u" 
> Position: 994
> ```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @MatBailie Same error when it's just `u` too.

Comment: I don't think you want the `_u.` in the returning clause, as it is implicit that you're referring to the table being inserted into.  You can't, as far as I know, return values from the source tables, only the destination table.  This means that you can't return values not being inserted in the destination table, even if they're in the source tables. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/sql-insert.html (look for `output_expression`)

Comment: @MatBailie: What you say is basically correct and explains the observed error. Still, it can make sense to use the table alias of the target relation, and we can get the desired values in the `RETURNING` clause. See below. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's true, as has been noted, that the `RETURNING` clause of an `INSERT` only sees the inserted row. More specifically, [quoting the manual here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-insert.html#id-1.9.3.152.5):

> The optional `RETURNING` clause causes `INSERT` to compute and return
> value(s) based on each row actually inserted (or updated, if an `ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE` clause was used). This is primarily useful for
> obtaining values that were supplied by defaults, such as a serial
> sequence number. **However, any expression using the table's columns
> is allowed.** The syntax of the `RETURNING` list is identical to that
> of the output list of `SELECT`. Only rows that were successfully
> inserted or updated will be returned. [...]

**Bold** emphasis mine.
So nothing keeps you from adding a **correlated subquery** to the `RETURNING` list:

```sql
INSERT INTO employees.password_resets AS ep
       (empl_pwd_reset_uuid                  , empl_user_pvt_uuid                    , t_valid                     , for_empl_user_pvt_uuid, token)
SELECT 'f70a0346-a077-11eb-bd1a-aaaaaaaaaaaa', '6efc2b7a-f27e-11ea-b66c-de1c405de048', '2021-04-18 19:57:47.111365', eu.empl_user_pvt_uuid , '19d65aea-7c4a-41bc-b580-9d047f1503e6'
FROM   employees.users eu
WHERE  empl_user_pub_uuid = 'e2bb39f1f28011eab66c63cb4d9c7a34'
RETURNING for_empl_user_pvt_uuid AS empl_user_pvt_uuid  -- alias to meet your org. query
        , (SELECT email
           FROM   employees.emails
           WHERE  empl_user_pvt_uuid = ep.empl_user_pvt_uuid
           ORDER  BY t DESC  -- NULLS LAST ?
           LIMIT  1
          ) AS email
        , (SELECT name_first
           FROM   employees.profiles
           WHERE  empl_user_pvt_uuid = ep.empl_user_pvt_uuid
           -- ORDER  BY ???
           LIMIT  1
          ) AS name_first;
```

This is also **much more efficient** than the query you had (or what was proposed) for multiple reasons.

- We don't run the subqueries `ee` and `ep` over all rows of the tables `employees.emails` and `employees.profiles`. That would be efficient if we needed major parts of those tables, but we only fetch a single row of interest from each. With appropriate indexes, a correlated subquery is much more efficient for this. See:

  - [Efficient query to get greatest value per group from big table](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/52015/3684)
  - [Two SQL LEFT JOINS produce incorrect result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12464037/two-sql-left-joins-produce-incorrect-result/12464135#12464135)
  - [Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group/7630564#7630564)
  - [Optimize GROUP BY query to retrieve latest row per user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25536422/optimize-group-by-query-to-retrieve-latest-row-per-user/25536748#25536748)
- We don't add the overhead of one or more CTEs.
- We only fetch additional data *after* a successful `INSERT`, so no time is wasted if the insert didn't go through for any reason. (See quote at the top!)

Plus, possibly most important, this is **correct**. We use data from the row that has actually been inserted - **after** inserting it. (See quote at the top!) After possible default values, triggers or rules have been applied. We can be certain that what we see is what's actually in the database (currently).

You have no **`ORDER BY`** for `profiles.name_first`. That's not right. Either there is only one qualifying row, then we need no `DISTINCT` nor `LIMIT 1`. Or there can be multiple, then we also need a deterministic `ORDER BY` to get a deterministic result.

And if `emails.t` can be NULL, you'll want to add `NULLS LAST` in the `ORDER BY` clause. See:

- [Sort by column ASC, but NULL values first?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9510509/sort-by-column-asc-but-null-values-first/9511492#9511492)

#### Indexes

Ideally, you have these multicolumn indexes (with columns in this order):

- `users (empl_user_pub_uuid, empl_user_pvt_uuid)`
- `emails (empl_user_pvt_uuid, email)`
- `profiles (empl_user_pvt_uuid, name_first)`

Then, if the tables are vacuumed enough, you get three index-only scans and the whole operation is lightening fast.

#### Get pre-`INSERT` values?

If you really want that (which I don't think you do), consider:

- [Return pre-UPDATE column values using SQL only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7923237/return-pre-update-column-values-using-sql-only/7927957#7927957)

Answer (score 1):

According Postgres Docs about [6.4. Returning Data From Modified Rows](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/dml-returning.html) :

> In an INSERT, the data available to RETURNING is the row as it was
> inserted.

But here you are trying to return columns from source table instead of destination. Returning will not be able to return columns form `_u` table rather only from `employees.password_resets` table's inserted row. But you can write nested cte for insertion and can select data from source table as well. Please try below approach.

```
WITH _u AS (
    SELECT
        eu.empl_user_pvt_uuid,
        ee.email,
        ep.name_first
    FROM employees.users eu
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT DISTINCT ON (ee.empl_user_pvt_uuid)
            ee.empl_user_pvt_uuid,
            ee.email
        FROM employees.emails ee
        ORDER BY ee.empl_user_pvt_uuid, ee.t DESC
    ) ee ON eu.empl_user_pvt_uuid = ee.empl_user_pvt_uuid
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT DISTINCT ON (ep.empl_user_pvt_uuid)
            ep.empl_user_pvt_uuid,
            ep.name_first
        FROM employees.profiles ep
    ) ep ON eu.empl_user_pvt_uuid = ep.empl_user_pvt_uuid
    WHERE empl_user_pub_uuid = 'e2bb39f1f28011eab66c63cb4d9c7a34'
), I as

(
    INSERT INTO employees.password_resets (empl_pwd_reset_uuid, empl_user_pvt_uuid, t_valid, for_empl_user_pvt_uuid, token)
    SELECT 'f70a0346-a077-11eb-bd1a-aaaaaaaaaaaa', '6efc2b7a-f27e-11ea-b66c-de1c405de048', '2021-04-18 19:57:47.111365', _u.empl_user_pvt_uuid, '19d65aea-7c4a-41bc-b580-9d047f1503e6'
    FROM _u
)
select _u.empl_user_pvt_uuid, _u.email, _u.name_first from _u
```